# Change the range of rangeinput of jquery tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I cannot find a way to change the maximum rangeinput for jquery tools. The default one is 300. I would like it to become 400 but I cannot find any resource how.

Thanks for th help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have this option clearly stated in their site http://www.jquerytools.org/documentation/rangeinput/index.html

You can check this demo http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/rangeinput/index.html

You have to use the max attribute in input elements

```
<input type="range" name="test" min="100" max="400" value="150" />
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/VnMaY/1/)